# Obout Tree AJAXPage could not be initialized warning message

Tags: asp.net, treeview, obout

We have used Obout Tree View for a page in our web application.It is working fine with local machine. When we published the solution to 64 bit server, same page is giving some warning message like this

> "AJAXPage could not be initialized.please make sure you have a 
>   tag defined for the page or you are using the Scriptplaceholder
>   property "

if clicked on cancel it is working but clicked on ok will navigate to obout.com.
Why this is happening?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8k86.jpg)

Comment: How do you refer to that ajax page in your code?